# Using column as a table name while join

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I want to get some rows from posts table. I use eloquant and, I don't know how do I make it.

I have five tables :

- suspended_users (foreign_key - article_id -> post_translations.id)
- post_translations (post_id (`posts-reviews` or `specs`) and `post_table`)
- posts (mean contents)
- reviews
- specs

I want to **jump those three tables from** `suspended_users`.

And I tried to *below way inside of Suspect model*.

But doesn't work!

```
$this->join("post_translations as pt", "pt.id", "=", "suspended_users.article_id")
            ->join($this->post_type." as p", "p.id", "=", "post_translations.post_id")
            ->select($this->post_type.".*")
            ->get();
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `DB::raw` function. Try this:

```
$this->join(\DB::raw("post_translations as pt"), "pt.id", "=", "suspended_users.article_id")
            ->join(\DB::raw($this->post_type." as p"), "p.id", "=", "post_translations.post_id")
            ->select($this->post_type.".*")
            ->get();
```

Comment: $this->post_type returns null, it causes problema

Comment: So the problem is not in the join itself, but in the attribute of the object. You have to fix this before joining.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$this->select("p.*")->join("post_translations as pt", "pt.id", "=", "suspended_users.article_id")
            ->join($this->post_type." as p", "p.id", "=", "post_translations.post_id")
            ->get();
```